# Removing information from debug.getinfo in Lua?

Tags: file, api, function, lua, stack

Using debug.getinfo(number), people are able to see which files I load through luaL_dofile and which strings I run through luaL_dostring. I'm trying to secure my scripts, so how would I go about hiding or removing my files and strings from debug.getinfo?

Overriding debug.getinfo isn't an option for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try precompiling your scripts with `luac -s`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the C function `luaL_dostring` use the Lua function `load`:

1. push the string
2. push "="
3. get global "load"
4. call (load)
5. call (the compiled string)

For `luaL_dofile`, read the file to a string.

Comment: The Lua load function is disabled in this program. Would I be able to use lua_load so that it wouldn't provide much information to debug.getinfo?